# Using beautifulsoup and urllib library to find li tag

Tags: python

I am trying to find all Li tag text and make list of it.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request
url = 'https://www.armashutter.com.au/'
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
tt=soup1.find_all("li")
```

but after that get_text() not working..can anybody help how to extract all texts from it.

Comment: what does "not working" mean? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where exactly are you facing the problem?

```
In [300]: from urllib.request import urlopen,Request
          url = 'https://www.armashutter.com.au/'
          soup1 = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
          tt=soup1.find_all("li")

In [301]: [x.text for x in tt]
Out[301]:
['Home',
 'About us',
 'Roller ShutterResidential Roller ShuttersCommercial Roller ShuttersSpecialised Roller Shutters',
 'Residential Roller Shutters',
 'Commercial Roller Shutters',
 'Specialised Roller Shutters',
 'Security Doors',
 'News',
 'Gallery',
 'Contact Arma Shutter',
 'Roller Shutters Melbourne – Best shutters',
 'About us',
 'Products',
 'News',
 'Gallery',
 'Contact Arma Shutter']
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct asnwer!

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://ikman.lk/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

Li_data = soup.find_all('li')
print(Li_data)
```

It's all available in the official [documentation.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a parser

```
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.armashutter.com.au/'
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), 'lxml')
tt=soup1.find_all("li")
print(tt)
[<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-38" id="menu-item-38"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/">Home</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37" id="menu-item-37"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/about-us/">About us</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-185" id="menu-item-185"><a href="#">Roller Shutter</a><ul class="sub-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36" id="menu-item-36"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/products/cheap-roller-shutters/">Residential Roller Shutters</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35" id="menu-item-35"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/products/commercial-roller-shutters/">Commercial Roller Shutters</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33" id="menu-item-33"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/products/specialized-roller-shutters/">Specialised Roller Shutters</a></li></ul></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36" id="menu-item-36"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/products/cheap-roller-shutters/">Residential Roller Shutters</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35" id="menu-item-35"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/products/commercial-roller-shutters/">Commercial Roller Shutters</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33" id="menu-item-33"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/products/specialized-roller-shutters/">Specialised Roller Shutters</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-175" id="menu-item-175"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/cheap-security-doors/">Security Doors</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30" id="menu-item-30"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/news/">News</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29" id="menu-item-29"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28" id="menu-item-28"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/contact-arma-shutter/">Contact Arma Shutter</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-47" id="menu-item-47"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/">Roller Shutters Melbourne – Best shutters</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46" id="menu-item-46"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/about-us/">About us</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45" id="menu-item-45"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/products/">Products</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43" id="menu-item-43"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/news/">News</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-42" id="menu-item-42"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>, <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41" id="menu-item-41"><a href="https://www.armashutter.com.au/contact-arma-shutter/">Contact Arma Shutter</a></li>]
```